# Automatically scroll the div tag vertically; issue with code

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code which scrolls the div automatically. When we move the cursor on to the particular div it stops scrolling, and after removing the cursor from the div it will automatically start from the same position. The code is working fine but sometimes it is not working, can any one resolve the issue ?

```js
ScrollRate = 20;

function scrollDiv_init() {
 DivElmnt = document.getElementById('MyDivName');
 ReachedMaxScroll = false;

 DivElmnt.scrollTop = 0;
 PreviousScrollTop = 0;

 ScrollInterval = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
}

function scrollDiv() {

 if (!ReachedMaxScroll) {
  DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
  PreviousScrollTop++;

  ReachedMaxScroll = DivElmnt.scrollTop >= (DivElmnt.scrollHeight -
   DivElmnt.offsetHeight);
 } else {
  ReachedMaxScroll = (DivElmnt.scrollTop == 0) ? false : true;

  DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
  PreviousScrollTop--;
 }
}

function pauseDiv() {
  
 clearInterval(ScrollInterval);
}

function resumeDiv() {
 PreviousScrollTop = DivElmnt.scrollTop;
 ScrollInterval = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
}
```

```html
<html>
   
   <body onLoad="scrollDiv_init()">
      <div class="inner" id="MyDivName"  onMouseOver="pauseDiv()" 
         onMouseOut="resumeDiv()"> 
         ...........elements like (P ,img etc)....
      </div>
</html>
```

Comment: turned your code into a snippet. There are issues with the code. Fix them first

Comment: is there any other approach to scroll the div vertically,  on mouse hover it will stop scrolling ????

Comment: Can you try to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) such as a mini snippet and what you expect to do? Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moqaOv

Comment: Shouldn't `setInterval('scrollDiv()',` be `setInterval(scrollDiv,` ? here's a tutorial which should help: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/